# Changes in tp_compare vs. tp_richcompare between python 2 and 3?

Tags: api, python-3.x, comparison, python-2.x, cpython

I am dealing withpython module which implements comparison operator or its objects ([pygts](http://pygts.sf.net), wrapping the [GNU Triangulated Surface Library](http://gts.sf.net)).

Py2 version defines `tp_compare` function pointer, which is a simple function testing for equality of the wrapped types, and it works fine.

When compiled for Py3, I assign the `tp_richcompare` function pointer, and the function is a simple proxy which calls the old comparison when the operation is equality test, otherwise returns "not implemented", as per rich comparison protocol ([github](https://github.com/woodem/woo/blob/master/py/3rd-party/pygts-0.3.1/segment.cpp#L455)):.

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
  static PyObject* rich_compare(PyObject *o1, PyObject* o2, int op){
    switch(op){
      case Py_EQ:{
         if(compare(o1,o2)) Py_RETURN_TRUE;
         Py_RETURN_FALSE;
      }
      default: Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
    }
  }
#endif
```

Now when I run code which works in py2 under py3, I get crash with this backtrace line:

```
#6  0x00007f8b27a71c82 in rich_compare (o1=0x7f8aedf946f0, o2=0x9e6720 <_Py_NoneStruct>, op=2) at py/3rd-party/pygts-0.3.1/segment.cpp:459
```

which says the `o2` is `None`.

How is it possible that there is no crash in py2? Does the py2 interpreter do the `None` check for me, and py3 does not? I cannot find any documented change here.

Thanks for hints.

**EDIT:**

Adding

```
 if(o2==Py_None) Py_RETURN_FALSE;
```

at the beginning of rich_compare made the crash go away, so my guess is correct, it seems. Documentation on that still appreciated.